# Custom search with Custom Fields in WP REST API?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

Good morning! Is there any way to do searches with the WordPress REST API with custom fields, being more specific, I have some custom posts, with a custom field of a specific date, and I want to do a search of those same posts between two specific dates, and that print the result to me in the JSON that WordPress sends

Comment: No, WP won't recognize custom field dates as dates that can be searched between. If the custom field has been added to the REST API then you can search for it, but you would need to search for every individual date that's in your desired range. You can pull from the REST API and then use PHP (or whatever language you're using) to search through the data for posts within a date range.

Comment: @WebElaine so I have to do that coding a plugin or in the functions.php? Or just pull all the data and sort it after it?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771940/2611917) basically would cover what you're trying to do with a little tweaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this plugin that made my life easier, so I didn't have to code all that

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-filter/